# See if Python2 code will compile in Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have Python2.7 installed on my computer. Is there a way to see if the .py code I have will compile in Python3 short of installing Python3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this program: https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

It will convert your code form 2 to 3, or give you information about what needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your code or operating system, it's hard to say what would be best. If static analysis is the way you want to go, I would suggest taking a look at this to see if any differences jump out at you:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#common-stumbling-blocks

By the way, Python 2 and 3 can be installed simultaneously on the same machine without too much effort if you change your mind.

If you're running Linux: [Running both python 2.6 and 3.1 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082692/running-both-python-2-6-and-3-1-on-the-same-machine)

If you're running Windows: [How to install both Python 2.x and Python 3.x in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809314/how-to-install-both-python-2-x-and-python-3-x-in-windows-7)